# Please keep your [support-bintray-release] in the upright and locked position

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The tag [support-bintray-release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support-bintray-release) doesn't make any sense, it has no description, it is not used, and generally what does it even mean?

[bintray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bintray) tag is specific enough.

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [bintray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bintray) and [artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: There are no questions in that tag?

Comment: There was one (the one it was introduced at), but I replaced it with the right one ([tag:bintray]).

Comment: The [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34828426/2) that introduced the tag says that it was specified in "the library's readme". [A plugin](https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release) mentioned in the question does, in fact, request this tag: *"Looking for community help… use the tag: support-bintray-release when posting a new question"*

Comment: Duh! Now at least it's clear where it comes from. I'll issue a pull request on GitHub to use the normal [tag:bintray] tag. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release/pull/92

Comment: Off topic, belongs on https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Congratulations with completing your first burninate-request all by your self :-)

By removing the tag from the one and only question with that tag you made the tag eligible for the tag clean-up script that runs at [03:00 UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253197/158100). After that the tag will be gone.

One burninate request down, 1000 more to go.

Comment: Maybe in your timezone? I'm pretty sure it runs at 03:00 UTC or it must have been changed recently. Most daily scripts run in that timeslot.

Comment: @yellowantphil sure here is at least one reference for the 03:00 UTC: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177326/accidentally-created-the-teaxx-tag/177327#comment533467_177327

Comment: That's a very low bar for congratulations :) It wasn't that hard :) Thanks anyway.